# how to display traffic site in page with google analytics

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

i'm starter in google analytics, i create user for web site and get js code and past code in the all page in website. i want showing traffic  webbsite in my site with google analytics data, example total visitor, today visitor, lastMonth visitor, last yearvisitor and ...,but I do not know how to implement it, please help me. thanks all

Comment: Here you go: https://developers.google.com/analytics/ .

Comment: @styxxy: i read this page but i do n't now how to implement this. thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) - No programming necessary.  Simply define you chart and paste a snippet of code in your page where you want the chart to display.

Comment: @M Schenkel: thanks for help me. but i want write code, and i don't use component. thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnettips.info/Post/858/ Persian Link

Comment: this post implement asp.net mvc, but i want implement by asp.net web forms. thanks for help me.